# The boxes of doom

Tags: probability

Say that you have two boxes, both of which contain one red ball and two green balls. You draw one ball out of each, one at a time, except that you stop drawing as soon as you get a red ball. So, if the ball you get out of box 1 is red, you don't get anything out of box 2. If the ball you get out of box 1 is green, you move on to box two and draw a ball out.

What's the chance of getting the red ball? A table reveals that it should be $\frac{3}{7}$:

```
+---------+---------+-------------------+
|  BOX 1  | BOX 2   | AT LEAST ONE RED? |
+---------+---------+-------------------+
| RED     | -       | Y                 |
| GREEN 1 | GREEN 1 |                   |
| GREEN 1 | GREEN 2 |                   |
| GREEN 1 | RED     | Y                 |
| GREEN 2 | GREEN 1 |                   |
| GREEN 2 | GREEN 2 |                   |
| GREEN 2 | RED     | Y                 |
+---------+---------+-------------------+
```

That is, 3 favourable cases out of seven possible ones.

However, I need to generalise this to a case of $n$ boxes and a variable mix of red and green balls, and that's when things start breaking down.

So now you have $n$ boxes. Each contains a mix of green balls and red balls. Let $r_i$ be the chance to get a red ball from box $i$, and $g_i = 1 - r_i$ the chance to get a green ball.

As before, you draw only one ball out of each box, and one at a time. Green ball, you move on to the next box; red ball, you stop drawing immediately. You can ever get at most one red ball.

Say that $R_i$ is the event of getting the green ball out of the first $i-1$ boxes and the red one out of box $i$; it has probability $P(R_i)= g_1g_2\cdots g_{i-1}r_i$. This means that, if you do get the red ball, only one of the following events happened:

$R_1$, *or*

$R_2$ (i.e., a green ball out of box 1 and red ball out of box 2), *or*

$R_3$ (a green ball out of the first two boxes and a red ball out of box 3), *or*

$\dots$

$R_{n-1}$ (a green ball out of the first $n-2$ boxes and a red one out of box $n-1$), *or*

$R_{n}$ (a green ball out of the first $n-1$ boxes and a red one out of box $n$).

Say that $R$ is the event of getting a red ball. The probability $P(R)$ of getting the red ball *should* be the chance of any of these events happening, and since they're all mutually exclusive, I thought that

$$P(R) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(R_i).$$

Except it doesn't quite seem to work.

If we try the above formula in the case of two boxes with one one red ball and two green balls each, we get

$$P(R) = P(R_1) + P(R_2) = r_1 + g_1r_2 = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{9}= \frac{5}{9}.$$

That's too much, and as you can see by making a table, that's actually the chance of getting *at least* a red ball *without stopping at all at the first red ball*.

```
+---------+---------+-------------------+
|  BOX 1  | BOX 2   | AT LEAST ONE RED? |
+---------+---------+-------------------+
| RED     | GREEN 1 | Y                 |
| RED     | GREEN 2 | Y                 |
| RED     | RED     | Y                 |
| GREEN 1 | GREEN 1 |                   |
| GREEN 1 | GREEN 2 |                   |
| GREEN 1 | RED     | Y                 |
| GREEN 2 | GREEN 1 |                   |
| GREEN 2 | GREEN 2 |                   |
| GREEN 2 | RED     | Y                 |
+---------+---------+-------------------+
```

As you can see, nine combinations total, five of which have at least a red ball. The formula is counting cases where the red ball was drawn first as separate, while they should all count as one. I have been thinking about this for a while, but I was unable to find the right formula.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second table is the relevant one. Think of it like this: even if you draw a red ball from the first box of doom, you might as well draw a ball from the second box of doom too, just for fun. This way, each of the nine possible outcomes has the same probability.

The problem with your first table is that not all outcomes have the same probability. The probability of the first outcome is $\frac13$, but the probability of each subsequent item is $\frac19$. So you get $\frac13+\frac19+\frac19=\frac59$, the same as the second table.

Comment: Looks like you accidentally double-posted? (I'm upvoting the first version :-)

Comment: @joriki: yes, it looks like it, doesn't it? But how could that happen? I would have to edit, copy the text, cancel the edit, and post a new answer! (Which I promise you I didn't do.)

Comment: No, I'm sure you didn't :-) Perhaps a glitch in the system where you hit exactly the right microsecond where one thread didn't know yet that another one had already created the answer, or something like that...

Comment: Or perhaps there are two of me?

Comment: The TonyKs of doom!

Comment: Bwahaha${}{}{}$